# how mysql replication

Tags: mysql, database, replication, linux, mysql-replication

I'm doing mysql replication (master - slave). There are a few questions

- Can I assign replication for some databases and not all databases that are on master (for example, ON master server there are db's: a, b, c, d I want to do replication on a, b, c only)
- When I lock the table in the master server and export data. After exporting the data, I unlock the table on the master, After some time (three days) to start configuring the slave, then import data to master .I have a question: can  this replication process be active ?
- Question on backup data mysql: if the mysql DB is too large, can I use mysqldump to export long, the way I was not.

Answer (score 1):

> I can assign replication for some database not all on master (for
>   example, ON master server have db: a, b, c, d now just replication a,
>   b, c only) -

Sure, you can. Take a look at [--replicate-do-db](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-db) option.

> When I lock the table in the master server and export data .After
>   export data finish. I unlock table on the master . After a time (three
>   days) to start configuring the slave, then import data master .I have
>   question: can this replication process is active ?

Because it based on [master status](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-howto-masterstatus.html) when exporting data.

> Question on backup data mysql: mysql DB if too large, use mysqldump
>   to export long, the way I was not.

You can do it at the midnight.

Comment: Why midnight is less-busy? ;)